# Facing issue in a specfic flutter project while running over my ios device in flutter

Tags: flutter

Failed to establish a debug connection with 661e647d32d2bf1e57a60abeedda37a0af480e22 using mdns: Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for /Users/khattab/Desktop/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd/iproxy.

Comment: cable is new also as my iphone 8, and i can run other projects over the same device

Comment: Android, iOS for which device are you trying to build?

Comment: iOS device iPhone 8

Comment: Try to open your project in XCode. Then from Runner option, change the Display name to "Runner" if it is set differently.

Comment: Didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

There is no artifact, so probably build failed. You should check your debug console to see what is the exact problem.

Comment: build is successfully working and application is running, but there is no console logs, only the message which i wrote it up printed and it keeps loading